# Beautifulsoup returning same result when called in a while loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and trying to write a **scraper** to get all the links on page with multiple pagination.I am calling the following code in a while loop.

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(givenurl,"",10000)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

linktags = soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class':'paginationLink pageNum'}) 

page.close()

BeautifulSoup.clear(soup)

return linktags
```

It always returns results of the first url i passed. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the loop? Are you sure the url is different?

Comment: If there's a return within the loop it wouldn't iterate more than once either.

Comment: @uncollected: i bet you just nailed it

Answer (score 5):

@uncollected probably had the right answer for you in the comment, but I wanted to expand on it.

If you are calling you exact code, but nested in a `while` block, it is going to return right away with the first result. You can do two things here.

*I am not sure how you are using the `while` in your own context, so I am using a `for` loop here.*

Extend a results list, and return a whole list

```
def getLinks(urls):
    """ processes all urls, and then returns all links """
    links = []
    for givenurl in urls:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(givenurl,"",10000)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
        linktags = soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class':'paginationLink pageNum'}) 
        page.close()
        BeautifulSoup.clear(soup)
        links.extend(linktags)
        # dont return here or the loop is over

    return links
```

Or instead of returning, you can make it a [generator, using the `yield` keyword](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement). A generator is going to return each result and pause until the next loop:

```
def getLinks(urls):
    """ generator yields links from one url at a time """
    for givenurl in urls:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(givenurl,"",10000)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
        linktags = soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class':'paginationLink pageNum'}) 
        page.close()
        BeautifulSoup.clear(soup)
        # this will return the current results,
        # and pause the state, until the the next
        # iteration is requested    
        yield linktags
```